# Completely different results from lme() and lmer()

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I've been playing around with both `nlme::lme` and `lme4::lmer`.
I fitted a simple random intercepts model using `lme()` and `lmer()`. As you can see below, I got completely different results from `lmer()` and `lme()`. Even signs of coefficients are different! Am I doing something wrong? I also fitted an empty model with the two packages. In this case, the results were practically the same (results not shown). Would you educate me to understand this issue? Unless I made a mistake, I think there is something wrong with the `lme4` package.

```
     multi <- structure(list(x = c(4.9, 4.84, 4.91, 5, 4.95, 3.94, 3.88, 3.95, 
4.04, 3.99, 2.97, 2.92, 2.99, 3.08, 3.03, 2.01, 1.96, 2.03, 2.12, 
2.07, 1.05, 1, 1.07, 1.16, 1.11), y = c(3.2, 3.21, 3.256, 3.25, 
3.256, 3.386, 3.396, 3.442, 3.436, 3.442, 3.572, 3.582, 3.628, 
3.622, 3.628, 3.758, 3.768, 3.814, 3.808, 3.814, 3.944, 3.954, 
4, 3.994, 4), pid = 1:25, gid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))

#lme
> lme(y~x, random=~1|gid,data=multi,method="REML")
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: multi 
  Log-restricted-likelihood: 41.76745
  Fixed: y ~ x 
(Intercept)           x 
  4.1846756  -0.1928357 

#lmer

 lmer(y~x+(1|(gid)), data=multi, REML=T)
    Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
    Formula: y ~ x + (1 | (gid))
       Data: multi
    REML criterion at convergence: -78.4862
    Random effects:
     Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
     (gid)    (Intercept) 0.70325 
     Residual             0.02031 
    Number of obs: 25, groups:  (gid), 5
    Fixed Effects:
    (Intercept)            x  
         2.8152       0.2638
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/384539/28500) and try repeating with optimizer="nloptwrap" in `lmer`. If there are multiple optima in the REML criterion than you might not find the true optimum otherwise. Please then edit your post to specify whether or not that fixed your problem.

Comment: Data in graph is not good, because we cannot convert it into dataset. How about the variances of estimated intercept and slope? From the data, it seems that the relation between X and Y is very weak, so it is possible that tiny difference in algorithm can result in big difference on point estimates.

Comment: @user158565 Thank you. I edited my post and included the data. The correlation bewteen X and Y is indeed very strong (Pearson r=-0.99).

Comment: @Edm Thanks. I read it and tried a couple things but the results from lme() and lmer() are still completly different. Some of my colleagues used this example to argue that it is important to use a random intercept model (based on the results of lmer). However, I think it is a result due to malfunctioning of lmer or misusage of lmer. In this case, lme showed a correct (?) result. Would you tell me what's excatly going on and whether there is a way to produce similar results between lmer and lme? Thank you.

Comment: It seems lme has problem. I fit the model without random effect and got the exact the same results as lme. stdDev of random intercept is  7.800953e-07, which is wrong based on the estimate of gid effect as fixed. I will compare the results with SAS PROC MIXED.

Comment: I used getME(model,"X") and getME(model, "Z") on the lmer model. But I cannot find the way to get them from lme model.

Comment: @user158565 Thanks for your reply. It's interesting. I fitted the exact same model using Stata: mixed y x ||gid:, reml. The estimated coefficient for x was -.1928356, which is same as lme. I also conducted pooled OLS using R:lm(y~x, data=multi). The coefficient of x was -0.1928.

Answer (score 14):

As it was noted in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384528/lme-and-lmer-giving-conflicting-results/384539#384539), and also mentioned in one of the comments, the problem seems to be a local maximum. To see this more clearly I have written below a simple code to calculate the negative log-likelihood of this model and do the optimization using `optim()`. Starting with different initial values leads to the two different solutions:

```r
# data
multi <- structure(list(x = c(4.9, 4.84, 4.91, 5, 4.95, 3.94, 3.88, 3.95, 
                              4.04, 3.99, 2.97, 2.92, 2.99, 3.08, 3.03, 2.01, 1.96, 2.03, 2.12, 
                              2.07, 1.05, 1, 1.07, 1.16, 1.11), 
                        y = c(3.2, 3.21, 3.256, 3.25, 
                              3.256, 3.386, 3.396, 3.442, 3.436, 3.442, 3.572, 3.582, 3.628, 
                              3.622, 3.628, 3.758, 3.768, 3.814, 3.808, 3.814, 3.944, 3.954, 
                              4, 3.994, 4), 
                        pid = 1:25, 
                        gid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))

# function to calculate the negative log-likelihood of the random intercepts model
library("mvtnorm")
logLik <- function (thetas, y, X, id) {
    ncX <- ncol(X)
    betas <- thetas[seq_len(ncX)]
    sigma_b <- exp(thetas[ncX + 1])
    sigma <- exp(thetas[ncX + 2])
    eta <- c(X %*% betas)
    unq_id <- unique(id)
    n <- length(unq_id)
    lL <- numeric(n)
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        id_i <- id == unq_id[i]
        n_i <- sum(id_i)
        V_i <- matrix(sigma_b^2, n_i, n_i)
        diag(V_i) <- diag(V_i) + sigma^2
        lL[i] <- dmvnorm(y[id_i], mean = eta[id_i], sigma = V_i, log = TRUE)
    }
    - sum(lL, na.rm = TRUE)
}

# optimization using as initial values 0 for the fixed effects, 
# and 1 for the variance components 
opt <- optim(rep(0, 4), logLik, method = "BFGS", 
             y = multi$y, X = cbind(1, multi$x), id = multi$gid)

opt$par[1:2] # fixed effects
#> [1] 2.855872 0.250341
exp(opt$par[3]) # sd random intercepts
#> [1] 0.6029724
exp(opt$par[4]) # sd error terms
#> [1] 0.01997889

# optimization using as initial values 4 & -0.2 for the fixed effects, 
# and 0.0003 and 0.034 for the variance components 
opt2 <- optim(c(4, -0.2, -8, -3.4), logLik, method = "BFGS", 
              y = multi$y, X = cbind(1, multi$x), id = multi$gid)

opt2$par[1:2] # fixed effects
#> [1]  4.1846965 -0.1928397
exp(opt2$par[3]) # sd random intercepts
#> [1] 0.000270746
exp(opt2$par[4]) # sd error terms
#> [1] 0.03239167
```

Comment: Could you please recommend me a good book to learn the theory behind your implementation?

Answer (score 10):

I agree with @DimitrisRizopoulos's answer, and have a few more points to make.

- I will start by saying that I am unhappy that `lmer` doesn't find the best answer - even though I suspect this situation is probably limited to small, unusual (see below) data sets. One of the reasons that `lme` may do better is that it fits on the log-standard-deviation scale, which may make the minimum near zero "broader".
- You can get `lmer` to replicate the `lme` results by setting an explicit, lower starting value for the scaled standard deviation (`start=...`); based on the explorations below, `start=8` or any lower value should work OK. For what it's worth, this will lead to an estimated random effects variance of 0 (and a "singular fit" message, and an answer that's equivalent to leaving out the random effects component entirely and using `lm()` ...)
- In this particular case using the "nloptwrap" optimizer doesn't help; in fact all of the optimizers that `lmer` can use, starting from the default starting values ($\theta$ (scaled standard deviation) = 1.0), find the higher local minimum away from zero.
- here is code equivalent to the approach `lmer` uses to find the starting value by default, when only intercept-valued random effects are present (see 
  [here](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/modular.R#L547-L557)):

```
v0 <- with(multi,var(ave(y,gid)))  ## variance among group values  
v.e <- var(multi$y)-v0             ## residual var ~ total var - group variance
sqrt(v0/v.e)                       ## convert to scaled standard deviation
```

This leads to a starting value of $\theta=10.8$.

- We can see systematically how different starting values give different results:

```
m0 <- lmer(y~x+(1|(gid)), data=multi, REML=TRUE)
tvec2 <- seq(0,20,length=51)
ff <- function(t0) getME(update(m0,start=t0),"theta")
v <- sapply(tvec2,ff)
plot(tvec2,v)
abline(v=10.8,col="red")
```

[image]

- We can also explicitly visualize the (negative log-)likelihood surface:

```
## helper function to capture fitting trajectory
cfun  <- function(...) {
    cc <- capture.output(x <- do.call(lmer,c(list(...),list(verbose=100))))
    gfun <- function(x,s) {
        as.numeric(gsub(s,"",grep(s,x,value=TRUE)))
    }
    it <- gfun(cc,"iteration: +")
    xval <- gfun(cc,"\tx = ")
    fval <- gfun(cc,"\tf\\(x\\) = +")
    attr(x,"optvals") <- data.frame(it,xval,fval)
    return(x)
}

c0 <- cfun(y~x+(1|(gid)), data=multi, REML=TRUE)
c1 <- cfun(y~x+(1|(gid)), data=multi, REML=FALSE)

f <- as.function(m0)
tvec <- seq(0,100,length=101)
dvec <- sapply(tvec,f)
m3 <- update(m0,REML=FALSE)
f2 <- as.function(m3)
dvec2 <- sapply(tvec,f2)
par(las=1,bty="l")
matplot(tvec,cbind(dvec,dvec2),type="l",
        ylab="deviance/REMLcrit",
        xlab="scaled standard dev")
with(attr(c0,"optvals"),text(xval,fval,it))
with(attr(c1,"optvals"),text(xval,fval,it,col=2))
legend("bottomright",c("REML","ML"),
       col=1:2,lty=1:2)
```

[image]

The numbers show the sequence of values tried. We can see that it is only the *slightly* different shape of the ML curve that tips the optimizer toward the boundary fit rather than the interior fit.

- Are these data artificial? The left plot below shows the data by group; the right plot shows the values with their group means subtracted.  There is almost no variation among the 5 values within each group ...

[image]

- If we simulate data with the same properties (starting from the estimated coefficients), but where the variation is actually Gaussian, we don't get the same kind of multimodal surface at all:

```
multi_sim <- transform(multi,y=simulate(m0,seed=101)[[1]])
f3 <- as.function(update(m0,data=multi_sim))
dvec3 <- sapply(tvec,f3)
plot(tvec,dvec3,type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, the data are artificial extracted from a book. The author of the book provided this example to maintain that it is important to use a random intercept model by comparing the results from lm to lmer. Now that I read your comments, lmer with its default option failed to find the best solution.

Comment: maybe contact the author of the book and let them know ... ? (I'm curious what the book is myself, up to you if you feel like saying)