# lme() and lmer() give different estimates for crossed random effects

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a question on statistical mixed linear model analysis with nlme in R. There are a couple of posts that are related to my question, I think (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384528/lme-and-lmer-giving-conflicting-results) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385670/completely-different-results-from-lme-and-lmer/385780)), but I'm not sure they give the solution to my problem.

I would like to fit a linear mixed model to data from an experiment with crossed random effects for subjects and stimuli. Here are simplified data simulated based on my data and with great help from this [paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/2515245920965119) and the accompanying [R code](https://osf.io/56tgb/).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(nlme)

set.seed(1234)

# parameters for group
beta_0  <- 55.145 # intercept
omega_0 <-  3.644 # by-item random intercept sd
tau_0  <- 7.671 # by-subject random intercept sd
sigma  <- 26.683 # residual (error) sd

# number of subjects and items
n_subj <- 150 
n_items  <-  36 

items <- data.frame(
  item_id = seq_len(n_items),
  O_0i = rnorm(n = n_items, mean = 0, sd = omega_0)
)


subjects <- data.frame(
  subj_id = seq_len(n_subj),
  T_0i = rnorm(n = n_subj, mean = 0, sd = tau_0)
)


# add subject IDs
subjects1$subj_id <- seq_len(n_subj)


trials <- crossing(subjects, items)  %>%
  mutate(e_si = rnorm(nrow(.), mean = 0, sd = sigma))


dat_sim <- trials %>%
  mutate(y = beta_0 + T_0i + O_0i + e_si) %>%
  select(subj_id, item_id, y)
```

I would typically use `lme4::lmer()` to fit a model to this data but I have a between subjects factor in my experiment and the data turned out to be heteroscedastic. As far as I know, I need to use `nlme::lme()` to fit different residual variances for each between-subjects group, so `lme4::lmer()` is not an option. Now, I would like to fit a model in `nlme::lme()` that matches my original model in `lme4::lmer()`.

For demonstration, I fit intercept-only models. (In reality I would have fixed effects, too. But this is not relevant for the question I have.)

My `lmer()` model would look like this:

```
m.lmer <- lmer(y ~ 1 + (1|subj_id) + (1|item_id),
              data = dat_sim,
              REML = T,
              control = lmerControl(optimizer="nloptwrap"))
```

With the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643713/how-to-specify-different-random-effects-in-nlme-vs-lme4), I pieced this model together for `lme()`:

```
dat_sim$dummy <- factor(1)

m.lme <- lme(y ~ 1,
            random = list(dummy = 
                            pdBlocked(list(pdIdent(~subj_id-1),
                                           pdIdent(~item_id-1)))),
            data = dat_sim,
            method = "REML")
```

**And here is my problem**:
The two models give different estimates for fixed and especially random effects:

```
summary(m.lmer)$coefficients
#             Estimate  Std. Error     df  t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 54.08182  0.8576796 102.7496 63.05597 5.819007e-84

VarCorr(m.lmer)
# Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
# subj_id  (Intercept)  7.6215 
# item_id  (Intercept)  2.8036 
# Residual             26.4984 

summary(m.lme)
# Fixed effects:  y ~ 1 
#             Value    Std.Error    DF   t-value     p-value
# (Intercept) 53.66397 0.9505988 5399 56.45281       0

VarCorr(m.lme)
# dummy = pdIdent(subj_id - 1), pdIdent(item_id - 1) 
#           Variance     StdDev     
# subj_id  6.408743e-04  0.02531550
# item_id  6.743363e-03  0.08211798
# Residual 7.655888e+02 27.66927555
```

But if I remove one of the random effects, my results are identical across lmer() and lme():

```
m.lmer.s <- update(m.lmer, ~ 1 + (1|subj_id))
VarCorr(m.lmer.s)
# Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
# subj_id  (Intercept)  7.6072 
# Residual             26.6463

m.lme.s <- update(m.lme, random = ~1|subj_id)
VarCorr(m.lme.s)
# subj_id = pdLogChol(1) 
# Variance  StdDev   
# (Intercept)  57.86926  7.607185
# Residual    710.02435 26.646282



m.lmer.i <- update(m.lmer, ~ 1 + (1|item_id))
VarCorr(m.lmer.i)
# Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
# item_id  (Intercept)  2.7336 
# Residual             27.5727

m.lme.i <- update(m.lme, random = ~1|item_id)
VarCorr(m.lme.i)
# item_id = pdLogChol(1) 
# Variance   StdDev  
# (Intercept)   7.472733  2.73363
# Residual    760.252039 27.57267
```

Why do the models with both random effects give so such different results and why does this seem to depend on whether only one or both random intercepts are fitted? Is my model specification for `lme()` wrong? Or is there an issue with a local maximum when fitting two random effects with `lmer()` (see this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385670/completely-different-results-from-lme-and-lmer/385780))? Could anyone explain to me what is happening here?

Comment: The `nlme` results are nowhere near the simulated variances. This seems to suggest that the model you specified with `lme` does not do what you want it to do. I am more familiar with `lme4`, which to me looks correctly specified. Perhaps you should remove the `-1` part in the `lme` one since you don't have a random intercept like in the linked post?

Comment: Too late to edit, but I meant to say you don't have a random slope

Comment: @FransRodenburg Thank you for your comment. Yes, that makes sense, the results from `lme()` are not at all close to the intended variances. I tried removing the `-1` but this returns an error `Error in pdConstruct.pdBlocked(object, form = form, nam = nam, data = data,  : 
  cannot have duplicated column names in a "pdMat" object`

Comment: Your codes for both `lme` and `lmer` are fine. The disparity is because `subj_id` and `item_id` are generated as integers. They must be factors for `lme` to recognize as grouping levels instead of a continuous variable, unless they appear after `|` which is forbidden inside `pdBlocked()`. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643713.